# CMS FRA explanation

Tags: interest-rates, cms

do you know how works a CMS FRA?
CMS FRA confirmation is below.
What does 2.344% represent ?
why do we have Euribor in the confirmation?

Example:

```
Fixing date : 21 feb 2029
Settlement date : 23 FEB 2029
Settlement amount: 30Y ICE SWAP RATE 30/360 VS 6M Euribor
11AM FFT - (2.344% + 70 bps) * notional

Index reference : 30Y ICE SWAP RATE 30/360 VS 6M Euribor
11AM FFT on fixing date
```

Thanks